# button onClick execute javascript function and stop before redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, node-webkit

I have a button which onClick executes a javascript function.

I want the function to execute as it gets some values like the useName logged in and redirects to his profile. But after executing the function and getting the values and **BEFORE** redirecting to the url of the profile i want to stop it and add some parameters. Once the parameters are added, the redirection can be allowed.

How to do this with jQuery?

SAMPLE CODE:

```
<button onClick="userProfile()" />

<script>
function userProfile(){
var user = $.session.get('userName');
window.open('http://omg.com/' + user + '/profile.jsp/');
};
</script>
```

Once this url is ready to redirect, i want to set some values as querystring and then redirect to its destination.

Comment: can you add code snippet of what you have tried ?

Comment: please show us the code snippet

Comment: sample code added. plz have a look, ignore syntax errors, if any.

Comment: This looks fine. What issue you are facing ??

Comment: @SameerK Once the url is set i.e. ["http://omg.com/srk/profile.jsp"] for redirection, i want to add some values as querystring with this. Means it should look like [http://omg.com/srk/profile.jsp?fname:shah&mname:rukh&lname:khan/]... (just example)

Comment: You can construct URL before window.open. For example 
``var parms = "?fname:shah&mname:rukh&lname:khan/]";
var url = "http://omg.com/' + user + '/profile.jsp/"
window.open(url + params);`` 

Will this helps you ??

Comment: The function is already defined. Is it possible to insert code in an existing function using jquery?